# Bat error: ) was unexpected at this time (for if label subroutine)

Tags: batch

bash error: ) was unexpected at this time.
I need do something on all users, exept Administrator and Public

**Batch file**

```
@echo off
C:
CD \Users
for /D %%d in ("*") do (
 IF "%%d" == "Administrator" GOTO NEXT
 IF "%%d" == "Public" GOTO NEXT
 REM do something
 echo "%%d"
:NEXT
)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Public>batch.bat
) was unexpected at this time.
```

Thanks to "It Wasn't Me". The workable batch file in my case:

```
@echo off
CD \Users
for /D %%d in ("*") do (call :LOOP %%d)
exit /b

:LOOP

REM skip users
IF "%1" == "Administrator" GOTO NEXT
IF "%1" == "Public" GOTO NEXT

REM old users
IF EXIST "%1"\Desktop\Unif GOTO NEXT

REM GROUP 1
IF "%1" == id395 GOTO NEW1
IF "%1" == id483 GOTO NEW1

REM GROUP 2
IF "%1" == id488 GOTO NEW2

REM others
echo "do something"
GOTO NEXT

:GROUP1
echo "do something"
GOTO NEXT

:GROUP2
echo "do something"

:NEXT
exit /b

CD \Users\Administrator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the label outside the loop.

```bat
@echo off

CD /D C:\Users
for /D %%d in (*)do IF "%%~d"=="Administrator" (
     GOTO=:NEXT) else (echo "%%d")


:NEXT
rem :: do more command here...
```

- **Obs.:** Since you're using starting with an `if`, you don't need to use the `do (if() else())`, you can directly use the `do if() else()`

One alternative code to exclude user Administrator/Public:

```bat
@echo off

CD /D C:\Users

for /D %%d in (*
)do echo=\%%~nxd|findstr /vi "Administrator Public" >nul && (
     rem :: do your command's here
     echo\ Current loop folder: %%~nxd 
    )
```

- One option using `if() else if() else()` condition:

```bat
@echo off

CD /D C:\Users

for /D %%d in (*)do if /i "%%~nxd" == "Administrator" (
       rem./ Some likes do nothing/skipping...
     ) else if /i "%%~nxd" == "Public" (
     rem./ Some likes do nothing/skipping...
     ) else (
       rem :: do your command's here
       echo\ Current loop folder: %%~nxd 
     )
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

  [√] **[Rem](https://ss64.com/nt/rem.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Echo on | off](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**

  [√] **[Direct a batch program to jump to a labelled line: `goto :label`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)**

  [√] **[Call one batch program from another, or call a subroutine: `call :label`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)**